# How to have different calendars in Android?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I need to have different calendars in Android, because I want to add event calendar from my app but I don't want to add event in default calendar I would like other calendar. I want other calendar the same or similar default calendar. No custom Calendar. Is it possible?  Any idea? I hope that somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

In above code I added `A Test Event from android app` event to current date..

Comment: Yes. I know, this event is added in default Calendar. But I would like in other Calendar.